# Add JDBC in Netbeans Maven Project

Tags: java, oracle, maven, netbeans, jdbc

I have created a java maven project inside of netbeans. I now need access to an oracle database via my java code. I downloaded the jdbc driver (.jar file) from Oracle, now what do I do to include it into my maven repository inside of netbeans?

There is this link which is close to what I want to accomplish:
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-add-oracle-jdbc-driver-in-your-maven-local-repository/

I do not have maven installed on my computer, I have it running inside of netbeans.

What are the steps of adding a JDBC driver inside of a netbeans maven repository?

Cheers

Comment: Is the driver not available in the central maven repo? Right click "Dependecies" and select add dependency and of a search. You can also add the dependency Pom directly to the project Pom

Comment: @MadProgrammer No, the Oracle driver is not available via maven due to licensing, that is why I needed to download it manually.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there... I do not use Netbeans, but I'm almost sure that somewhere under it, it has maven installed.

So, try to locate the **mvn** executable, and follow the instruction provided in the link that you posted, or the [official instructions](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html) to do it.

Another try would be run the command `install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=<group-id> -DartifactId=<artifact-id> -Dversion=<version> -Dpackaging=<packaging>` as a goal, inside netbeans (again, I'm not a netbeans user, but since other tools allow it, maybe netbeans could do the same...).

A google search showed [this instructions](https://platform.netbeans.org/tutorials/nbm-maven-commandline.html). It may help you.